# Suspend/Wake Up not working - black screen

Tags: 13.10, suspend, hp

If I suspend laptop (closing lid, calling pm-suspend or doing it manually from menu), when I wake it up, everything seems to turn on except for screen. Screen remain literally off, so even backlight is deactivated.
Only way is to force shutdown.

I am on Ubuntu 13.10 with latest kernel (3.11.0-15-generic). 
My machine is an HP Pavilion DV6-2000sl laptop. 
VGA is AMD/ATI RV710/M92 [Mobility Radeon HD 4530/4570/545v]. Driver I'm using is open-source (radeon).

I tried much things found on the web (among which installing fglrx drivers), but nothing worked for me.

Here is [pm-suspend.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6710631/) and [cat /var/log/syslog | grep PM](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6710647/)

I was thinking of doing downgrade to a working version of Ubuntu (or a kernel), but I don't know what could it be.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same experience and by switching to the proprietary drivers for my video card (In my case nvidia) I was able to solve these problems.

The way I did this was quite simple. 
Ubuntu Software Center > Edit > Software Sources > Additional Drivers (switch to proprietary)

Comment: I tried that way, but I have not found stable proprietary drivers for my ATI video card.

Comment: I had this problem too on my old HP 844w / NVINDA Quadro and was fixed using the apropiate nvidia propietary driver. Thanks