# Variant on the NotWakingUpAfterSuspend problem

Tags: suspend, screen, xserver

I looked at many posts about this problem, but I could not find one that solved mine.

After I suspend or sleep my computer, it wakes up. I know because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> shows me a console. But my desktop screen remains black and is unresponsive.

How can I wake up my desktop from a working console on the same computer?

What I've tried:

- Running `set -display $DISPLAY dpms force on` did not work, but it did give me `unable to open display ""`. Same thing when I tried to set `DISPLAY=:0` manually.
- `sudo sysctrl unlock-session`: nothing happened
- I can't reproduce this yet, but twice I've gone to a graphical message like `your screen is locked. You will be forwarded to the unlock dialog` (can't recall the exact wording). But the screen ends up going black again.
- `startx` on the F1 console started an empty desktop fine. So in principle, graphics capabilities are there.
- `sudo system lightdm restart` wakes that screen with a login dialog. Since it kills all running applications it's not really helping.
- Found some other bounty question with references to `light-locker` and `xscreensaver`. Never heard of either before, but followed what I read there. So I purged `light-locker` and installed `xscreensaver xscreensaver-data xscreensaver-gl`. After I logged in, I was asked to confirm to disable the `lightlocker daemon` which I did. But the problem remained. Maybe I need to do something else?.

**Used Systems**

- Xubuntu 16.04, latest update
- Desktop PCs, Atom CPU's /Intel on Board Graphics Cards
- the problem is with several motherboards
- Monitors: standard VGA noName TFTs

Comment: Probably duplicated with https://askubuntu.com/questions/401675/suspend-wake-up-not-working-black-screen

Comment: @luisdarui sorry, no duplicate of that, because there the screen does not work at all. My screen works fine on F1-F6 console. Just F7 does not work

Comment: What version of `_ubuntu` are you using? Are you running desktop or laptop? What make and model? If you're not on a lapop what graphics card and monitor do you have?

Comment: Have you tried [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/602184/344926) already?

Comment: @Fabby That is what I meant with the last bullet point. Followed your lines and installed the xsaver stuff. Did not help. Maybe I missed sth you did not write, because it was meant for a pro not a newbie?

Comment: OK, then I cannot help you any further.

Comment: When GUI is not responsive - but CLI (eg.: F1)  Could you run a `ps -elf f` command? This lists all processes.
I just hope (especially if you run 32 bit systems) it is not the famous "futex_wait" problem.

Comment: @Fabby Good news, not sure what exactly is was but now your approach seems to work.  I am getting messages about gome screensaver deamon.  To get rid of that I  I tried to uninstall and purge  light-locker again and rebooted again. Next time it showed me after suspend a xscreensaver login screen.

Comment: .. (too slow to edit) So thanks a lot for your solution. Now, I am still getting this gnome screensaver deamon message which I believe should not be there. Can you please refine your linked answer with a bit more details to make it really failsafe. Also do you know by chance  how I can wake the new scr.s. from SSH cli?

Comment: @V-Mark I am running x64. Since there is a workaround now, I am still curious about this futex_wait. The ps -elf is a very long list I'd rather not post. Can I identify it myself? I mean what should one be looking for?

Comment: "futex_wait problem" is a kind of glich among program threads.
Intel Haswell and newer processors with 32bit is affected mostly.
I faced this problem when I had 32bit system (minecraft started or freezed after start 50-50% of the time). If you run `ps` with `-f` there is a column: WCHAN (waiting channel) - where that task is waiting. Some programs "frozen" = wait forever and they are in futex_wait.

Comment: As per your request: answer added and if you have any troubles, leave a comment below it.

Comment: Not even an upvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're having trouble with the Gnome screen-saver, replace it by the X Screensaver (which is what I did when I ran into a similar kind of issue:

- get rid of `gnome-screensaver` by:

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge gnome-screensaver
  sudo apt-get purge light-locker
  ```

*Note:* The light-locker purge should be automatic with the gnome-screensaver but as you were having trouble with that, added in as well.

- Install the X screensaver by:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install xscreensaver xscreensaver-data xscreensaver-gl
  sudo reboot
  ```

The reboot is in principle not necessary, but will ensure a "clean" system.

(It's just a workaround and not a real "solution" but it works for me and is definitely better then shutting down and restarting)

Comment: is there a way to assign the bounty after the expire time? Only reason not accepting your answer was being away from email access. System should be able to find out that I accepted the answer immediately after first reading it. So this should validate the bounty imho, as the time limit makes sense to limit the time for answers but not so much as to assign the bounty. As you seem part of the furniture here, maybe you know a way.

Comment: The bounty itself is just lost...  **¯\\_(ツ)_/¯**  But no worries: the acceptance is good enough for me, favour returned!.  **:-)**